# Password Change Function in c++

Tags: c++

I've got a program that asks users for username and password, this is how I've defined it :

```
        system("cls");
        cout << "Enter Your Usename Please:" << endl;
        cin >> staff_user;
        cout << "Enter Your Password Please:" << endl;
        cin >> staff_password;
        if (staff_user == "staff" && staff_password == "generic"){
            std.staff_menu();
        }
        else { cout << "Sorry, Information Entered Is Invalid" << endl; }
        system("pause");

        system("cls");
        main();
```

so once the right username and password is entered, user get to see the other menu, but the thing is, i'm looking for a way to change this later on, I mean I want to allow that person to change his/her password. What are the possible ways to do such a thing ?!

Comment: Do you want the change of password to be remembered between different executions of your program?

Comment: Yes @JosephMansfield

Comment: Then you need to write the password to a file. When you're checking the entered password, read in the one in the file and compare to that. However, if you actually want a secure login system and not just something you're doing to practice C++, then there's a lot more to learn.

Comment: No, I'm just looking forward to practice, okay, I know how to store and read from files, but how should I begin ? should I write a username and password inside the file, and check for it ?

Comment: If you're really asking "how do I implement a user authentication system", then that's _waaaaaaaaaaaaaaay_ too broad for a Q&A repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the password to be remembered for this execution of the program then you can have it as part of a class and this class be initialized at the beginning of main and then pass it as a pointer to the various parts of your program.

If you want it to exist between different executions of your program then you need to save it - the simplest way is simply writing to a file but if your program is going to get large (or have a lot of users) then the best way is the use of a database.

When saving a username/password combination to a text file I tend to write them to the same line with a deliminiter in between that will never exist in either username or password. Then when you try to log a user in or change their password you can loop through the file line by line until you find the right username.

Keep in mind though that in real life you should **NEVER** store a plaintext password.